# Override Content security policy document.write

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, meta-tags, content-security-policy, document.write

I have a Google Chrome Extension where I catch headers for each web request and look for some information in the headers. The websites that I am considering are just special and a few, and they send a default content-security-policy in the 'meta' tag of the source. Which blocks any javascript:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'none';" >
```

The websites also send me their real content-security-policy in the headers. In short, this content-security-policy in the headers should be taking effect after I have done with my information search in the headers. Because, after I find the information I am searching, I override the source and write the new content to the browser with document.write() with a content script sent from my browser extension.

First of all, I just don't understand which content-security-policy is taking effect where, because the source with a content-security-policy in meta tag doesn't care about the content-security-policy in the headers any more. The one in the meta tag is effective. Is that right?
Also, when I override the source with document.write() looks like no content-security-policy is taking effect any more. If I replace it in the 'meta' tag, the browser returns a warning in console saying that it had ignored it. The one in the headers is not taking effect at all. 
When does the browser evaluate the content-security-policy and is it any possible to re-evaluate it? or using the document.write() is the problem here?

Comment: CSP in the `<meta>` tag overrides the header at least in Chrome, see https://crbug.com/166096#c5 - does this answer your question?

Comment: Many thanks, it answers part of it. Do you know why the CSP is not effective any more after document.write(html); it behaves like there was no CSP defined?

Comment: AFAICT the outcome you want is for your webRequest-added CSP header to be applied after document.write resets the page. This seems to me a reasonable thing to expect and I'm surprised it didn't work right away. Consider opening a ticket on https://crbug.com.